# Error when creating a bootable USB on Windows

Tags: ubuntu, boot, usb, system-installation

I have Windows 10 and followed the exact steps in the tutorial and everything went smoothly up to [here](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#4-boot-selection-and-partition-scheme). Error when using a 32GB USB stick: Access to the device denied. This is the log:

```
Rufus x86 v3.9.1624
Windows version: Windows 10 64-bit (Build 18363.720)
Syslinux versions: 4.07/2013-07-25, 6.04/pre1
Grub versions: 0.4.6a, 2.04
System locale ID: 0x0409 (en-US)
Will use default UI locale 0x0409
SetLGP: OpenLocalMachineGPO failed - error 80004005
Localization set to 'en-US'
Notice: The ISO download feature has been deactivated because 'Check for updates' is disabled in your settings.
Found USB 3.0 device 'SMI USB DISK USB Device' (090C:2000)
1 device found
No volume information for drive 0x81
Disk type: Removable, Disk size: 32 GB, Sector size: 512 bytes
Cylinders: 3849, Tracks per cylinder: 255, Sectors per track: 63
Partition type: MBR, NB Partitions: 0
Disk ID: 0x49BEA369
Drive has a Windows 7 Master Boot Record
Scanning image...
ISO analysis:
  Image is an ISO9660 image
  Will use '/isolinux/isolinux.cfg' for Syslinux
  Detected Syslinux version: 6.03/20171017 (from '/isolinux/isolinux.bin')
Disk image analysis:
  Image has an unknown Master Boot Record
  Image is a bootable disk image
ISO label: 'Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS amd64'
  Size: 2.0 GB (Projected)
  Has a >64 chars filename
  Uses: Syslinux/Isolinux v6.03
  Uses: EFI
  Note: This ISO uses symbolic links, which will not be replicated due to file system limitations.
  Because of this, some features from this image may not work...
Using image: ubuntu-18.04.4-desktop-amd64.iso (2.0 GB)
Will reuse 'ldlinux.sys' and 'ldlinux.bss' from './rufus_files/rufus_files/syslinux-6.03/20171017/' for Syslinux installation

Format operation started
Requesting disk access...
Will use 'D:' as volume mountpoint
Deleting partitions...
No partition to delete on disk '\\?\PhysicalDrive1'
Opened \\.\PhysicalDrive1 for exclusive write access
Analyzing existing boot records...
Drive has a Windows 7 Master Boot Record
Clearing MBR/PBR/GPT structures...
Erasing 128 sectors
Deleting partitions...
Partitioning (MBR)...
● Creating Main Data Partition (offset: 1048576, size: 29.5 GB)
Closing existing volume...
Waiting for logical drive to reappear...
Formatting (FAT32)...
Using cluster size: 16384 bytes
Quick format was selected
Access denied
[0x00000006] The handle is invalid. - Retrying...
[0x00000006] The handle is invalid. - Retrying...
[0x00000006] The handle is invalid. - Retrying...
[0x00000006] The handle is invalid. - Retrying...
Format error: Access to the device is denied.
Re-mounted volume as D: after error

Found USB 3.0 device 'SMI USB DISK USB Device' (090C:2000)
1 device found
No volume information for drive 0x81
Disk type: Removable, Disk size: 32 GB, Sector size: 512 bytes
Cylinders: 3849, Tracks per cylinder: 255, Sectors per track: 63
Partition type: MBR, NB Partitions: 1
Disk ID: 0x095DA4A1
Drive has a Zeroed Master Boot Record
Partition 1:
  Type: FAT32 LBA (0x0c)
  Size: 29.5 GB (31665946624 bytes)
  Start Sector: 2048, Boot: Yes
Closed Windows format prompt
Found USB 3.0 device 'SMI USB DISK USB Device' (090C:2000)
1 device found
No volume information for drive 0x81
Disk type: Removable, Disk size: 32 GB, Sector size: 512 bytes
Cylinders: 3849, Tracks per cylinder: 255, Sectors per track: 63
Partition type: MBR, NB Partitions: 1
Disk ID: 0x095DA4A1
Drive has a Zeroed Master Boot Record
Partition 1:
  Type: FAT32 LBA (0x0c)
  Size: 29.5 GB (31665946624 bytes)
  Start Sector: 2048, Boot: Yes
```

Note: the .iso file is saved in my Downloads folder, and my USB stick is brand new and empty. HOWEVER, I couldn't format it on this computer when I put it in (it worked on the Windows 8 computer though). Yesterday I tried it with a 128GB USB, which was probably far too large, and it said that the device could not be handled.

Is there a problem with Rufus?

Comment: "Access denied":  you are running Rufus as administrator, aren't you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As indicated in the [Rufus FAQ](https://github.com/pbatard/rufus/wiki/FAQ#Incompatible_Software) there are a lot of applications, typically security solutions, that can prevent software like Rufus from accessing a USB Flash Drive.

Bear in mind that the list from the FAQ is far from being exhaustive.

Most likely, there is an application or service on your PC that is preventing access to the USB, and you may have to find out what it is. The other possibility is that you may have a hardware issue, in which case I would strongly encourage you to run a bad blocks check (which Rufus can do under `Show advanced format options`).